# How to get a portion of a string with a regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have this situation where I can have strings like this:

```
"Project\\V1\\Rest\\Car\\Controller"
"Project\\V1\\Rest\\Boat\\Controller"
"Project\\Action\\Truck"
"Project\\V1\\Rest\\Helicopter\\Controller"
"Parental\\Boat\\Action"
```

Just in case the string follow the pattern:

```
"Project\\V1\\Rest\\THE_DESIRED_WORD\\Controller"
```

I want to get THE_DESIRED_WORD.

That's why I'm thinking in a regular expression.

Comment: im lazy i would just `explode()` on \\

Comment: you can get `THE_DESIRED_WORD.` with same code that i write.

Comment: Also what do you mean by match the pattern?

Comment: Yep, if you take a closer look to the possible strings, some of them have different patters than: "Project\\V1\\Rest\\THE_DESIRED_WORD\\Controller"
For those, the explode() solution doesn't work :(

Comment: @Oriam please mark and up-vote the answer for others help. thanks

Answer (score 1):

to use a regular expression, you need to escape the slash twice : once for the PHP string and once for the regex

try this :

```
$tab = array(
    "Project\\V1\\Rest\\Car\\Controller",
    "Project\\V1\\Rest\\Boat\\Controller",
    "Project\\V1\\Rest\\Helicopter\\Controller",
    "Project\\V1\\Rest\\Water\\Controller",
);

foreach ($tab as $s) {
    preg_match("!\\\\([^\\\\]*)\\\\Controller!U", $s, $result);
    var_dump($result);
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but two questions:

1: Why the desire string is always in the second position of the string(index 1)

2: What if I want to validate as well the string match this pattern:
"Project\\V1\\Rest\\DESIRED_WORD\\Controller" and just in that case get the DESIRED_WORD?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str='"Project\\V1\\Rest\\Car\\Controller"
"Project\\V1\\Rest\\Boat\\Controller"
"Project\\V1\\Rest\\Helicopter\\Controller"
"Project\\V1\\Rest\\Water\\Controller"';


$line=explode(PHP_EOL,$str);

//print_r($line);

foreach ($line as $l){
 $x=explode("\\",$l);

  if($x[0]=='Project' && $x[1]=='V1' && $x[2]=='Rest' && $x[4]=='Controller' ){
    echo $x[3];
   }
}
```

Comment: With this line: "Parental\\Boat\\Action" you will get a unidentified index :(   $x[4]

Comment: Instead of work with explode() in this case is better to work with string build in functions. But as I don't want to be asking for:
"Project\\V1\\Rest\\" at the beginning and "\\Controller" at the end, I preferred to use the regular expression

Comment: *"I don't want to be asking for: "Project\\V1\\Rest\\" at the beginning and "\\Controller"* so you have just changed the pattern your matching - im confused - fixing the undefined index is ofcouse trivial

Answer (score 0):

Explode does the job using `\\` separator :

```
<?php

$str1 = "Project\\V1\\Rest\\Car\\Controller";
$str2 = "Project\\V1\\Rest\\Boat\\Controller";
$str3 = "Project\\V1\\Rest\\Helicopter\\Controller";
$str4 = "Project\\V1\\Rest\\Water\\Controller";

$arr1 = explode( "\\",$str1 );
$arr2 = explode( "\\",$str2 );
$arr3 = explode( "\\",$str3 );
$arr4 = explode( "\\",$str4 );

echo $arr1[ 3 ] . ", " .
     $arr2[ 3 ] . ", " .
     $arr3[ 3 ] . ", " .
     $arr4[ 3 ];

?>
```

Will display:

```
Car, Boat, Helicopter, Water
```